# Invert + and -, < and > signs in Excel cells AND formulas

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an enormous Excel 2016 workbook, where (for financial reasons) all incomes are represented as negative figures, and all costs as positive figures.

I need to:

- invert the + and - signs in all workbook's contents.
- invert the > and < signs in all workbook's formulas.

I cannot just use "paste special" with multiplication by `-1`, because while this method would work with cells' values, it would not work with the formulas' text and it would not invert neither the + and - signs, nor the < and > signs of every figure inside formulas.

For instance, suppose I have cell `A3` with value `-150`, and cell `B4` with value `20`.

And I have formulas like  `=IF(-A3< B4,A3*-5,A3*2)`.

I need cell `A3` to become `+150`, and cell `B4` to become `-20`.

AND I need the formula to become `=IF(-A3>B4,A3*5,A3*-2)`.

I fear I should use some sort of VBA code, but I am frankly null at this.
Would anyone please help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: And you want to invert all the cell values to opposite number? I.e. negative to positive and vice versa? Or you want to change the sign of every number in formula? Like `-5` to `5` and `2` to `-2`?

Comment: Michal, I realized my question was not completely clear and I have rephrased it. Yes, all cell values should change sign, AND I need to have + and - signs inverted inside formulas, as well as < and > signs. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are cells `B4` and `A3` defined by formulas or they are just entered values?

Comment: They may be both....... and they may refer to the same worksheet or another one.......

Comment: So, generally, you want to multiply all cells by `-1` and inside the formula, if there is any, you want to replace `>` by `<` and vice versa?

Comment: I want to multiply all cells by -1 and inside the formula, if there is any, I want to replace > by < and vice versa, AND I want to replace - by + and viceversa. I guess it's damn complex. To me at least....

Comment: Couldn't you just format all negative numbers to display as positive, and all positive numbers to display as negative, and then leave all the values and all the formulas unchanged?  Do the users actually enter values on the sheet, or is it just a report?

Comment: Yow, thank you. Unfortunately it's an actively used workbook. Users do enter values.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Sub Replacement()
Dim rng, c As Range
Dim fml As String
'set it to the range you want
Set rng = Range("A1:C4")

For Each c In rng

    If c.HasFormula Then
        'if cell contains formula, then...
        fml = c.formula
        fml = fml & "*(-1)" 'flip the sign
        fml = Replace(fml, "<", "~!@~") 'change temporarily to some unique string
        fml = Replace(fml, ">", "<")
        fml = Replace(fml, "~!@~", ">") 'replace temporary string to character we want
        c.formula = fml
        Else
            'if it's value, just multiply by -1
            c.Value = c.Value * -1
        End If

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michal. This code seems to change the < by > and viceversa. 
Also, it seems to multiply the RESULT of a formula by -1.
If so, I don't have to change the sign of the RESULT of the formula, but instead, I would need to change EACH sign of each numeric figure INSIDE the formula....